# How to prove that a Group is cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I have to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3$ is cyclic by finding a generator. Using the usual operation on product group, addition, I found that
$$
(1,1)+(1,1)+(1,1)+(1,1)+(1,1)+(1,1)=(0,0).
$$ Hence we have that $(1,1)$ has order $6$. How to finish this argument? Could be enough my arguments such that $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3$ to be cyclic? What is the point with the generator?

Comment: A cyclic subgroup with the same order as the group is equal to that group, don't you think? However, you have to check the order of $(1,1)$ is indeed $6$, not one of its divisors.

Comment: I am sure that the order is $6$ because I added $(1,1)$ one by one:$$ (1,1)+(1,1)=(0,2), (0,2)+(1,1)=(1,0), ....$$. Now, who is the cyclic-subgroup? The one generated by $(1,1)$? And I am not sure that $(1,1)$ is a generator.

Comment: It is a generator since it has order $6$. Further more, the *Chinese remainder theorem*, in its abstract version, asserts this ring is  isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k(1,1)=(0,0),$ where $k\in\mathbb N$.

Thus, from the first coordinate $k$ is divisible by $2$ and from the second coordinate $k$ is divisible by $3$.

Can you end it now?

Comment: Do you suggest me that the order can be obtain by taking the least common multiple of $2$ and $3$? So the order of $(1,1)$ is $6$ and then...?

Comment: @stefano Yes and $k=6$ is a minimal such natural number. Now, use that $|\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_3|=6.$

Comment: Now it is clear. Thank you!